Azure Machine Learning Studio integration with rocker Rstudio: Git tab is not appearing for an Rproject set up with GitHub repository
I am running and Rproject with GitHub version control in Rstudio within a compute instance in Azure Machine Learning Studio. The Rproject was previously set up outside of Azure MLS and is running seamlessly with the Rstudio Git integration. When cloning the repository with the Rproject on another machine (not in Azure), the Git integration functions fine and the Git tab appears in Rstudio upon opening the project.
However, my team is transitioning to Azure Machine Learning Studio for running many of our larger models. We have currently gotten a compute instance set up with a custom application for running Rstudio. The compute instance is running Linux 23.06.30. It is using CPU processing (2 cores, 14 GB RAME, 28 GB disk). SSH access is disabled, root access is enabled. It is utilizing a private IP and is operating on a virtual network for our company.
The Rstudio custom application is rocker-rstudio. The target and published ports are 8787. The docker image is rocker/geospatial:4.3.1. The bind mounts are /home/azureuser/cloudfiles:/home/azureuser/cloudfiles.
The GitHub repository with the Rproject is cloned into the Users network directory (Notebook). The repo has been successfully accessed via VS code, so it has been properly cloned and is functioning.
However, when I open an Rstudio session within a compute instance and open the Rproject file, the Git tab does not appear in the Rstudio interface. So, the Rstudio docker does not seem to be detecting the .git information included in the cloned repository and saved as settings in the Rproject.
I have several related questions: Has anyone encountered/solved this issue? Is this a function of the docker image itself? Or is this some sort of communication issue between the Rstudio docker interface and Azure Machine Learning Studio settings?
I have tried manually enabling the Git settings in Rstudio. Initially, when I went to the Tools<Project Options<Git/SVN, "none" was enabled under Version control system. I manually intialized git, hoping that it would then recognize the git settings for the project, but this did not work. Now, it shows Git as the version control system, but under Origin it still says "none". This is not an editable field.
Within the Rproject directory, I went into the .git folder and opened the config file - under remote origin, it has the proper url for the github repository. So, somehow the rocker Rstudio is not recognizing this information. I have also manually set my user name and email both within the terminal in Azure MLS and within the Rstudio docker. The repo has also been added as a safe directory.
I found someone online who had a similar issue with Rstudio not initializing the Git tab, see here. However, the circumstances are not the same. He was on a Windows OS and not using a docker Rstudio image. However, the issue was that the location where git was stored did not have admin privileges for his machine and somehow that was interfering with how Rstudio integrates with git. I have checked with our IT department about admin priveledges to /usr/bin/git where the git.exe file is stored on our Azure system, and they are checking into this possibility, but it might take a while.
I have also tried running usethis::use_git() in Rstudio docker to try to manually force Rstudio to recognise the git repository. But while it says that it has set the active project to '/home/rstudio/cloudfiles/code/Users/chandra.goetsch/GitHub/desktop-tutorial', the origin repo still does not appear under the Project Options Git settings and no Git Tab appears. (I also restarted the R session and this doesn't seem to do anything).
I have also tried committing and pushing changes to repo using the terminal in the Rstudio docker session. This seems to work fine. I get a pop-up asking for my Github user name and token and the push occurs with no problem. However, some of the people on our project are not comfortable using command line to update the repository and I have to admit that I really like using the Git tab in the GUI to be able to track what changes I have made in a session and easily stage to commit and mark other files as .gitignore. I would really like to be able to have the Azure/Rstudio/Git integration be seamless and have the option of the Rstudio git tab interface available.
I would be extremely grateful to anyone for any answers on this behavior. Thanks so much in advance.
